# NextJS adding access token to client side request is not working

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios

I have been stuck on this for more than 2 weeks now and would really appreciate the help.

I have an axios interceptor that is supposed to add the access token stored in my cookies to the header of every request. Currently for requests coming from getServerSideProps to my backend everything is working and the access token is getting attached.

For requests coming from client Side eg handleAddProduct(), the only way they work is by adding the token to each header, wehn i remove the header i keep getting forbidden 403 Error.

I am using nookies to store the tokens in the cookies when the user logins in

```
await storeTokensInCookies(null, { access: access, refresh: refresh });

export const storeTokensInCookies = async(ctx, data) => {
  const { access, refresh } = data;

  setCookie(ctx, 'accessToken', access, {
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Expires in 30 days
    path: '/',
  });

  setCookie(ctx, 'refreshToken', refresh, {
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Expires in 30 days
    path: '/',
  });
};
```

Here is my Axios Interceptor

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {storeToken,storeAccessTokenInCookies} from './storage';
import { parseCookies, setCookie } from 'nookies';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
});

const refreshToken = async (ctx = undefined) => {
  try {
    const refreshToken = parseCookies(ctx).refreshToken;
    console.log("Sending refresh token request with:", refreshToken);
    const { data } = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}token/refresh/`, { refreshToken });
    console.log("Received data:", data);
    if (data.access) {
      saveAccessToken(data.access, ctx);
      return data.access;
    } else {
      console.error('No access token returned from the API');
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error refreshing token:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const customConfig = config.config || {};
  console.log('axios interceptor custom config isServerSide',customConfig.isServerSide)

  if (!config.url.includes('/token')) {
  if (customConfig.isServerSide&&typeof window === "undefined") {
    console.log('SERVER SIDE REQUEST')
    const { req } = customConfig;
    const cookies = parseCookies({ req });
    const accessToken = cookies['accessToken'];

    if (accessToken) {
      console.log('ACCESSTOKENZ server',accessToken)
        config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    }
} 
else {
  console.log('CLIENT SIDE REQUEST')

  const accessToken = getAccessToken();
  console.log('ACCESSTOKENZ client 1',accessToken)

    if (accessToken) {
      config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    }
}
  } else{
    console.log('Accessing /token route, skipping Authorization header.');
  }
  
  return config;
}, error => Promise.reject(error));

let isRefreshing = false;
let failedQueue = [];

const processQueue = (error, token = null) => {
  failedQueue.forEach(prom => {
    if (error) {
      prom.reject(error);
    } else {
      prom.resolve(token);
    }
  });

  failedQueue = [];
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    async (error) => {
      if (!error.response) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
  
      const { config, response: { status } } = error;
      const originalRequest = config;
      if (status === 401||status === 403 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        if (isRefreshing) {
          try {
            const token = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              failedQueue.push({ resolve, reject });
            });
            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
          } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
          }
        }
  
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        isRefreshing = true;
  
        try {
          console.log('TRYING REFRESH MECHANISM')
          const token = await refreshToken();
          axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
          originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
          processQueue(null, token);
          return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
        } catch (err) {
          processQueue(err, null);
          return Promise.reject(err);
        } finally {
          isRefreshing = false;
        }
      }
  
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
  

export default axiosInstance;
```

Currently my problems are the header not getting attached to client side requests unless manually added to each request and the refresh token logic (my endpoint is /token/refresh)

Thank you and really appreciate the help.